# Spring 4.0 form validation issue using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am facing problem when i am doing server side form validation using jQuery and spring 4. Every time "result" (object of BindingResult) is coming with zero error result.

Below I am proving my code for better understanding.
my jsp code is

```
  <div class="registerForm">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Register</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-signin" id="regForm" commandName="userRegister">
                                <div class="reg-error error"></div><div class="reg-success success"></div>
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username">
                                <input type="text" name="emailAddress" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
                                <input type="text" name="confirmEmailAdd" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Confirm Email address">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
                            </form>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitRegister">Register</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

my script code is

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register",    
                data: $('#regForm').serialize(), 
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result) {},
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){}
            });
```

My controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody 
    ValidationResponse register(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userRegister") @Valid UserRegister userReg, BindingResult result) {
        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
            List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
            for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
                errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(), objectError.getField() + "  " + objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
            res.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);

        } else {
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        }
        return res;
    }
```

My bean object

```
public class UserRegister {

    @NotEmpty @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty @Email @NotNull
    private String emailAddress;

setter and getters....
}
```

Do i need to do any other configuration or something else to get it validated properly?

app-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.app.security.handler.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <bean id="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.app.security.handler.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- bind your messages.properties
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>
         -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the userReg model object with the attributes (username, email etc) fields getting submitted to the server?

If not, The form fields may not be getting bound correctly to the model object

Try

```
 <form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="userRegister">
```

Also, the input fields needs to have the mapping to the model object

```
<form:input path="username" />
```

Also ensure that is set in the context file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Here is a demo :http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api

Also confirm that the validator jars are present in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you please list the spring xml configuration file (the file that has the below line in it)?

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: getting exception: ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userRegister' available as request attribute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userRegister' available as request attribute

Comment: withut form:form tag also, i was able to see the values inside the userreg object..in my controller

Comment: I checked all the configurations..everything is looking fine..i am not able to identify the problem :(...it must be some configuration issue

Comment: check this demo..see what's diff from your setup http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api

Comment: Above things..did help me :(...I am doing ajax call....in ajax call..do i need to do something different

Comment: @sourabh...correct me if i am wrong 1. your controller is receiving the model object. 2. The model object comes with the attributes populated with the respective form field values. The problem we are facing is that when the form fields are empty,the validation does not kick in and bindResult.hasErrors is empty. Right?

Comment: I dont want to use ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "username","message"); this kind of validation...I want spring, to do it for me..

Comment: found same question..but nobody answered,...http://www.coderanch.com/t/603461/Spring/BindingResult-showing-errors-form-Validation

Comment: Saurabh..here is a really good resource i always follow. Try this tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation

Comment: it seems more to me that spring is not picking up your notempty and notnull annotation. hibernate validator is present in your pom right? Also, try setting min and max size through annotaiton @size and see if validators pick errors on size. Atleast, we will know if validators kick in at all.

Comment: Tried it just now..still it is coming empty :(....I am not using maven for jars but hibernate-validator and validator-api is there in my classpath

Comment: it seems more to me that spring is not picking up your notempty and notnull annotation. hibernate validator is present in your pom right? Also, try setting min and max size through annotaiton @size and see if validators pick errors on size. Atleast, we will know if validators kick in at all.  Try this and see if min size and max size gets picked up by the error

Comment: I have tried that..it is not picking up that validation also

Comment: Can you please list the spring xml configuration file

Comment: only diff i see between urs and the tutorila is 1. xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc & corresponding schema  and 2. <annotation-driven /> in the spring xml configuration file.

Comment: After this tag, it is working :)..Thank you Paul for your great help and obviously, for bearing me...I wasted my two days into this issue :(...I have one more question..I need your suggestion on that...How can I create DAO layer using hibernate..there are two ways to do it 1. Create generic DAO 2. Create DAO class for each entity..I am new in Hibernate...I am unable to decide which way I should go..I want to keep everything simple, non-redundant code and straight forward, If possible self generated code kind of.

Comment: HI saurabh, here is a good tutorial that explains this in detail. http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4 Hope this helps.